# WORDPRESS Get Filename to use as ALT

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, filenames, alt

I have been using this code to set `alt` text to equal the `title` as the alt text is missing. Previously though I had used `$attr['alt'] = $attr['title'];` in order to use the filename as `alt`. It, however contains hyphens, so now I am trying to find a different way to get the filename.

I have read quite a few suggestions on how to retrieve the filename but so far nothing is working. Would also like to remove the file extension.

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'change_attachement_image_attributes', 20, 2);
function change_attachement_image_attributes($attr, $attachment) {
global $post;
$product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
if ($post->post_type == 'product') {
    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $image_filename = get_post_meta($image_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', TRUE);
    $attr['alt'] = basename($image_filename);
    }
    return $attr;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: "...  It however contains hyphens ...", so why not replace the hyphens with white spaces then?

Comment: ah yes, I had tried this also with ```str_replace("-", " ", $attr['title'])``` but couldn't get it working either. I thought maybe that wasn't possible. I have zero coding experience. Any tips on getting it working?

Comment: ..."but couldn't get it working either", why not? What happened?

Comment: actually I dont know now what I did wrong, as I have tried again and it is working for the main image but creates an error on the archive page ```undefined index:title``` and no alt is displayed for the thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your current code works (I have not tested it) you can simply replace hyphens in title with spaces:

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'change_attachement_image_attributes', 20, 2);
function change_attachement_image_attributes($attr, $attachment) {
global $post;
$product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
if ($post->post_type == 'product') {
    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $image_alt = get_post_meta($image_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', TRUE);
    $attr['alt'] = str_replace("-", " ", $attr['title']);
    }
    return $attr;
}
```

Comment: the str_replace line works on the main image but on the archive page I get an ```undefined index:title``` error.